# Network Dataset connecting link file - no links

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, network, arcgis-10.5

I've produced a network from ITN and Urban Paths data, and both sets of data work separately, however you cannot route between the paths and the road network because no connecting links were created. Has anyone had this problem before?